# Node.js , MongoDb, MongoSkin

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I m trying to use MongoDB with Node.JS using mongoskin, and I m facing a problem.

I start my DB with mongod and it works great, in fact, when I try to connect with "mongo" command, I see a new user connected.

But when I try to connect using mongoskin, nothing happened in the nodeJs console nor in the mongoDb console.

This is my little piece of code :

```
var express = require('express'),
mongoskin = require('mongoskin'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var db = mongoskin.db('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

app.use(bodyParser());

app.listen(3000);
```

It seems like everything works great, but I cant see the user connection in the mongoDb console.

Any idea ?

Comment: My guess is that mongoskin won't connect to your database until you actually perform a command like `db.collection('mycollection').find({}, function(err, result) { console.log(result); });` and see what happens.

Comment: Also, you might want to append "?auto_reconnect=true" at the end: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test?auto_reconnect=true